# OSX scroll bars for TMemo and TListBox

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, tmemo

Using Delphi XE7 Firemonkey

I've dropped a TMemo on a blank form and then added more lines of text to the TMemo than it can hold (so that scrolling is necessary).

On Windows everything works as expected. The vertical scroll bar appears when the TMemo has more lines than can be displayed.

On Mac, nothing visual appears where the scroll bar should be.

I can click on the TMemo and use the mouse wheel to scroll. I can also press the up and down arrow keys on the keyboard to scroll.

What would prevent the scrolling tools from appearing when the mouse is hovering over the TMemo?

Comment: FMX, DX10 Update 1. Works good on Android 6.0.1.

Comment: @Zam.  Good to know.  Now, how about OS X which is what the OP was asking about ?  ;)

Comment: @Mike at Bookup - OS X can be configured to only show scrollbars when "in use".  Do the scrollbars appear when the mouse moves over the memo or when scrolling ?  Is your OS X system configured this way ?  Or could it be that FMX always behaves this way, irrespective of that setting.

Comment: @Deltics My Mac shows scroll bars for everything that scrolls. It appears to be just my app that has nothing visual to click on where the scroll bars would appear.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the AutoHide property to False.
See http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/FMX.Memo.TMemo.